# How to avoid clearing of the form state?

Tags: 7, forms

I want to add form field based on data provided in submit handler. I am using `$form_state` for the job. I have done similar in the past but now it's just not work

Form code:

```
function module_form($form_state) {
 if (isset($form_state['module']['data'])) {
   //add field
 }
}

function module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['no_redirect'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  unset($form_state['redirect']);
  $form_state['module']['data'] = module_get_data($some_value);
}
```

Inside module_form `$form_state` is always empty...

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
function module_form($form_state) {
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
function module_form($form, &$form_state) {
```

The function sig for forms changed in Drupal 7 to the second example above.

Comment: Haven't you forgot an `&` or two? I was sure at least $form_state is to be taken by reference.

Comment: @Mołot Indeed I have, cheers for that